# Accessing a saved file in a .exe. Java

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I have written a program in java and have stored some data in a txt file. I then made the project into an .exe file using launch4j, and I was wondering how I can access the data stored in the file which should be in the .exe.

I have tried using getClass().getResource(file).path(); to get the file path, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I used URL instead of File and it has worked. So thanks :) As for why, the person who this program is for only ever uses the Windows OS and would not consider using another OS. I know that wrapping it in an exe wrapper defeats one of the main benefits of java. They specifically asked for it to be a .exe file, so I did that for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

If you used wrapping option of launch4j, then you cannot simply obtain resources from .exe. You would have to somehow parse/reverse engineer the exe file to obtain just the .jar content.

I doubt that there is some software for this, since you can simply decide **not to wrap** the jar with exe in the first place. Then you will have separate .exe file that server as a launcher for a independent .jar file. Its quite easy solution and really simple in an application.